# Payday 2 Place Sentry in AP Mode

Tags: payday-2

Is it possible to change the default mode sentries are placed in?  Currently mine are placed in the standard mode, but I only ever use AP mode

A [Steam discussion post](https://steamcommunity.com/app/218620/discussions/8/358415206094960188/#c358415206095314893) I found suggests it is possible, as well as disabling the toggle action, but links to a [dead pastebin page](https://steamcommunity.com/linkfilter/?url=http://pastebin.com/24Ny3JqN)

Being able to place sentries in AP mode would be a great time and ammo saver

Comment: If mods are okay for you, you can try Wolfhud, it has a setting for that: https://steamcommunity.com/app/218620/discussions/8/135514287302191315/

Comment: @Sentry thanks, it'd be nice if this was possible without a mod, but I doubt that's possible.  On the other hand, I managed to get the code in the discussion to work, will post it as an answer in a bit (still fiddling with some things)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only solution I've found so far is to use a mod

Using the code from the [Steam discussion post](https://steamcommunity.com/app/218620/discussions/8/135514287302191315/#c135514287302483931) *(thanks for the link, [@Sentry](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/26705/sentry))*, I got it working

1. Install the mod loader, BLT

   - Google ["Payday 2 BLT"](https://www.google.fi/search?q=Payday+2+BLT) and it should show up.  [Current download link](https://paydaymods.com/download/)
   - Copy the downloaded .zip contents into `Steam\SteamApps\common\PAYDAY 2\`
2. Create the APSentry mod

   - Create an `APSentry` folder in `Steam\SteamApps\common\PAYDAY 2\mods\`
   - Create a `mods.txt` file in the `APSentry` folder
   - Create a `APSentry.lua` file in the `APSentry` folder

**mods.txt** contents:

```
{
    "name" : "APSentry",
    "description" : "Places sentries as AP sentries",
    "author" : "",
    "contact" : "",
    "version" : "1",
    "updates" :
    [
        {
            "revision" : 1,
            "identifier" : "APSentry"
        }
    ],
    "hooks" :
    [
        {"hook_id" : "lib/units/interactions/interactionext", "script_path" : "APSentry.lua"}
    ]
}
```

**APSentry.lua** contents:

```
local setup_original = SentryGunFireModeInteractionExt.setup

function SentryGunFireModeInteractionExt:setup(...)
    managers.enemy:add_delayed_clbk("sentry_switch_" .. tostring(self._unit:key()), callback(self, self, "_auto_switch_firemode"), 0)
    return setup_original(self, ...)
end

function SentryGunFireModeInteractionExt:_auto_switch_firemode()
    if self:is_owner() then
        if not self._sentry_gun_weapon._use_armor_piercing then
            self:interact(managers.player:player_unit())
        end
        self:set_active(false)
    end
end
```

Comment: Couldn't figure out a way to format the code in the bullet points, looking back on it, it'd probably be more cluttered that way